# perl - weird loop behavior with ReadKey

Tags: perl

For some reason, in my simple menu program, weird things happen as a result of ReadKey()

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict ;
use warnings ;
use English ;
use Term::ReadKey ;

my @available_choices = ('choice one', 'choice two', 'choice three') ;
my $array_size = scalar (@available_choices) ;

print "\nPlease make your selection from the options below:\n\n" ;

for (my $i=0, my $j=1 ; $i < $array_size ; $i++, $j++) {
  print "$j) $available_choices[$i]\n" ;
}

my $key = undef ;
for (my $k=0; $k < 5; $k++) {
  print "\nSelection :> " ;
  $key = ReadKey();
  if ((defined $key) && ($key =~ /[1-$array_size]/)) {
    print "\nYou selected \"$available_choices[$key-1]\"\n" ;
    last ;
  }
  else {
    sleep 1 ;
  }
}
```

So if you run this simple program and give 1, 2, or 3 as your selection it works as expected. If you enter anything else (to trigger the else block) the loop iterates like 3 or 4 times before ReadKey() accepts input, again. Best illustrated by this output (I entered xxx and then "Selection:>" printed 3 times before I was able to type yyy):

```
$ ./bar.pl 

Please make your selection from the options below:

1) choice one
2) choice two
3) choice three

Selection :> xxx

Selection :> 
Selection :> 
Selection :> 
Selection :> yyy
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `ReadKey` reads *a key*.  When you press <kbd>x</kbd> 3 times and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>, that's 4 keys.  In fact, even a correct selection (<kbd>1</kbd>  <kbd>Enter</kbd>) is 2 keys; you just don't notice because your program exits immediately.

This is less obvious because the default input mode buffers keystrokes until you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  At that point, `ReadKey` will start to return each keystroke one at a time.

The solution depends on the behavior you're looking for.  If you want to have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> before acting on the input, then you can just read a line at a time (with the standard [`<>`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I/O-Operators) operator).  You don't need [`Term::ReadKey`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Term%3a%3aReadKey) at all.

If you want to take action immediately after a keypress, you'll need to use `Term::ReadKey`'s `ReadMode` function to change the input buffering.  Don't forget to add `END { ReadMode(0) }` to restore the original mode when your program exits.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your program reads a key, goes into the else loop and sleeps while you type your other characters, then continues. You may be suffering from buffering in that the print does not happen immediately when using sleep.

Your program could use some alternative methods. Here's an example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

my @available_choices = ('choice one', 'choice two', 'choice three') ;

print "\nPlease make your selection from the options below:\n\n" ;

# Using a block to reduce scope of $i
# No need to use a separate variable for the array length
{ 
    my $i = 0;
    say ++$i, ") $_" for @available_choices;
}

# No need to use a temp variable for a loop
# Also, might be better off with an infinite loop, 
# rather than one with 5 cycles.

#for (0 .. 4) {
while (1) {
    print "\nSelection :> " ;
    chomp(my $key = <>);     # Using STDIN instead of ReadKey
    last if $key =~ /^q$/i;  # easy exit
    next unless $key =~ /^\d+$/;
    if (defined $available_choices[$key-1]) {
        say qq(\nYou selected "$available_choices[$key-1]"\n);
        last;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I'm one month into using perl and it shows... thanks for the cleaner code. I have to google to figure out what `say` does and what this regex means `/^\d+$/`.  Thanks!

Comment: Neat. I love google. I can't use say b/c I'm stuck with perl 5.8, but print works well enough. \d matches digits. Of course. I feel smarter, now. :-)

Comment: `perldoc -f say`, `perldoc perlre` is right at your command prompt. You can also find this documentation at [perldoc.perl.org](http://perldoc.perl.org) `say` is just print with a newline at the end. `/^\d+$/` means: ^ start of string, \d digit, + match one or more times, $ end of line. In other words, it checks if there are **only** digits in the string.

Comment: You **are** a little bit smarter now. ;)

Comment: Question: How would I catch control-d (EOF)?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, never done that. I imagine you can check it with `eof`, since `<>` is a filehandle. You might find [Data::Dumper](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data::Dumper) valuable when trying to figure out what your variables contain. E.g. `$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print Dumper $var; print Dumper \@array`